# ez attempt to attribute NULL

Tags: r, null, anova

I want to conduct a within-subj Anova using the `ezANOVA` function from the ez package
this is my code:

```
> ezANOVA(data = sht_mean_cond_molten, dv = "value",
          within = "variable", wid = "id", detailed = TRUE,
          type = 2)

Fehler in table(data[, names(data) %in% c(wid, within)]) : 
Versuch ein Attribut von NULL zu setzen
Error message means "attempt to set an attribute on NULL"
```

what might be the problem?

Comment: If you make your problem reproducible using a small, self contained example, we can help you with a concrete advice. Until then...

Comment: Providing a dput or sampling of `sht_mean_..` would be helpful.  Please see [here](http://bit.ly/SORepro)